# WSO2 and CMIS connector

Tags: sharepoint, cmis, wso2-esb

I would like to know if WSO2 ESB :

1. has a dedicated connector for CMIS ?
2. has a dedicated connector to sharepoint ?

I didn't found any examples about such integration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All connectors which have currently been released can be found at https://github.com/wso2/esb-connectors/tree/master/distribution. The Sharepoint and CMIS connectors have not been developed yet.

Answer (score 2):

Recently Sharepoint connector has been added to WSO2 store. The Connector zip file can be downloaded from [here](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/75a79519-2f0b-4ff6-a30a-01f835b1a969). Go to the link and click the 'download connector' button and follow the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/SharePoint+Connector) for the configuration.